# Regression and time series. As it is called?

Tags: regression, time-series, arima

A long time ago I was studying time series, and I found something like this:

$Y_{t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X_{1}+\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}Y_{t-1}+\alpha_{2}Y_{t-2}+\epsilon$

i.e. $Y_{t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X_{1}+AR(2)$, combining a regression model and a T.S. model.

(Sorry, maybe there was some mistake at my expression or I've misunderstood something)

Do you know what is the name of this topic? Can you recommend some book or examples?
All kinds of help/ideas/advice needed and appreciated! :)

Comment: There isn't any "regression model" piece here as distinguished from a "time series" piece.  Perhaps you meant to write $\beta_1 X_t$?  (Without something like that, the model you've written isn't identified.)  In that case, you would have an ARX model.

Comment: Yes! it's an ARX. Do you have any suggestions of books about it?

Answer (score 3):

As you note, your model is an ARX(2) model. I'd recommend you look at Rob Hyndman's [The ARIMAX model muddle](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) blog post for a short discussion that contrasts ARIMAX models with regressions with ARIMA errors, which are easier to interpret.

I'm not aware of any books specifically on this topic, but if you are mostly interested in regression with ARIMA errors, then you can of course refer separately to textbooks on regression and to textbooks on time series analysis, for instance [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* by Hyndman & Athanasopoulos](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/). Or you may find [previous questions tagged both "arima" and "regression"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arima+regression) helpful.